# How to read a stream until it ends with a string

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am trying to read a Stream which will read until it ends with some string. I came up with some solution but I do not believe it is very good solution because of lots of string conversion and call to method in loop. Could someone please suggest me better solution.

```
  private static String readUntilEndsWith(BufferedReader reader,
                                          String endString) throws IOException
  {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (!buffer.toString().endsWith(endString))
      buffer.append(reader.readLine());
    return buffer.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Looks alright to me..

Comment: Have you run this through a performance monitoring tool and determined that there is a performance problem in this code? If not you should remove all performance optimizations from it (StringBuffer, for example), until that determination has been made. Simple, readable code is extremely valuable, and you shouldn't make things more complicated than required. Performance tuning is often a lot more complicated than you'd think, and simple, obvious, solutions usually aren't simple or obvious.

Comment: @EngineerDollery What alternative to `StringBuilder` do you suggest? The OP wants to collect all the input up to a given string.

Comment: @christopher not to me. There's no need to evaluate all the read string when you only want/need to evaluate the last line read.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young evaluate on the last line read, not on the whole content read.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well, of course I agree with _that_. But you still need to collect the return value via a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the current line only and evaluate it. If the line is *ok*, append it into your `buffer` and keep reading. This way you only evaluate the current line in the `reader` and not the whole content.

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null && !line.endsWith(endString)) {
    buffer.append(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
if (line != null) {
    buffer.append(line);
}
return buffer.toString();
```

Comment: Not the downvoter but this does not produce the same output as the OP expect. You need to add the last String in the buffer. Say the text file contains "Hello","world", the OP expects "Hello world" as output while your code will only output "Hello" as you don't add the `endString` in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If your `endString` is always a string that is in a line, then you can remake your condition to:

```
String line="";
do{
      line=reader.readLine();
      buffer.append(line);

}while (!line.endsWith(endString));
```

this way you do not have to convert your Buffer each time to a string.

P.S.
i also recommend using `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`
if your `endString` is however something that might be a sum of few lines, you can add something like:

```
if(endString.endsWith(line) {
    if(buffer.toString().endsWith(endString)
        return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: true, my mistake. Correction done. Also changed loop type, so `endString` will be in outcome